# Is there a way to decrease request download time for requirejs with Apache Tomcat 9.0.48 +?

Tags: requirejs, tomcat9

I have an application loading modules via requirejs running on an Apache Tomcat server (9.0.48). When upgrading from tomcat 9.0.46 to 9.0.48, I've noticed inconsistent page loading with error `Load timeout for modules: ...`.

When the module loading fails, Content Download time for the larger modules (jquery, wysihtml5) goes from ~100ms to 1 minute. Overall, the entire page load time increased from ~500ms to ~600ms. I haven’t observed download times larger than 200ms with `tomcat-coyote` from tomcat 9.0.46; seems like this is new with the 9.0.48 `tomcat-coyote` lib.

**Is there a way to speed up the module download times?**

### Configuration

**requirejs config**

requirejs loaded as data-main:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/configurator/assets/js/lib/utils/require-2.3.6.min.js" data-main="/configurator/assets/js/main"></script>`

```
requirejs.config({
  "paths" : {
    "jquery" : "lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.3",
    "jquery-ui" : "lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
    "fileupload" : "lib/jquery/jquery.fileupload",
    "jquery.iframe" : "lib/jquery/jquery.iframe-transport",
    "jquery.ui.widget" : "lib/jquery/jquery.ui.widget",
    "jquery.ba-hashchange" : "lib/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange",
    "underscore" : "lib/utils/lodash-1.0.0-rc3.min",
    "wysihtml5" : "lib/xing-wysihtml5/wysihtml5-0.3.0",
    "wysihtml5_parserrules" : "lib/xing-wysihtml5/advanced",
    "bootstrap" : "lib/bootstrap/bootstrap-2.1.0.min",
    "can" : "lib/can/can",
    "configurator" : "app/configurator",
  },
  "shim" : {
    "jquery": {
      "deps" : [ ],
      "exports" : "jQuery"
    }
    "underscore" : {
      "deps" : [ ],
      "exports" : "_"
    },
    "less" : {
      "deps" : [ ],
      "exports" : "less"
    },
    "fileupload" : {
      "deps" : [ "jquery" ],
      "exports" : "fileupload"
    },
    "bootstrap" : {
      "deps" : [ "jquery-ui" ],
      "exports" : "bootstrap"
    },
    "jquery-ui" : {
      "deps" : [ "jquery" ],
      "exports" : "jquery-ui"
    },
    "jquery.iframe" : {
      "deps" : [ "jquery" ],
      "exports" : "jquery.iframe"
    },
    "jquery.ui.widget" : {
      "deps" : [ "jquery" ],
      "exports" : "jquery.ui.widget"
    }
  },
  "modules" : [ {
    "name" : "main"
  } ],
  "appDir" : ".",
  "baseUrl" : "../../../configurator/assets/js",
  "waitSeconds": "0"
});

require([
    'jquery',
    'can',
    'underscore',
    'configurator',
    'bootstrap'

], function($, can, _, Configurator) {
   ...
   });
});
```

**Tomcat Connector config**

```
<Connector port="8443" address="0.0.0.0" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" emptySessionPath="false"
               maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2"  sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
               keystoreFile="..." keystorePass="..." keystoreType="..."
               useBodyEncodingForURI="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               ciphers="..." />
```

Comment: Can you see the slow requests in the browser dev tools network panel?

Comment: I can! The content download completes after exactly 1 minute inconsistently; the modules that exhibit the large download time are large themselves (> 100KB). An example for the wysihtml5 module:
`Queueing: 4.35ms
Stalled: 1.91 ms
Request sent: 0.27ms
Waiting (TTFB): 17.96ms
Content Downloaded: 1.0min`

Normally the content download time for this module is around 100ms.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears to be fixed in Tomcat 9.0.52. Associated Bug: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65448